# Php echo , change of manner of printing

Tags: php

i've got this quick question:

I have this code which is all ok, but what i need is to print it in a different way, and i've tried something but the problem is, i don't get any error, but the result doesn't go the right way,

The code i'm trying to print is this:

```
<ul class='star-rating' id="star-rating-<?php echo $star['id'];?>">
<?php /* getRating($id) is to generate current rating */?>
  <li class="current-rating" id="current-rating-<?php echo $star['id'];?>" style="width:<?php echo getRating($star['id'])?>%"><!-- will show current rating --></li>
  <?php 
  /* we need to generate 'id' for star rating.. this 'id' will identify which data to execute  */
  /* we will pass it in ajax later */
  ?>
  <span class="ratelinks" id="<?php echo $star['id'];?>">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star out of 5" class="one-star">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star and a half out of 5" class="one-star-half">1.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 stars out of 5" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 star and a half out of 5" class="two-star-half">2.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 stars out of 5" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 star and a half out of 5" class="three-star-half">3.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 stars out of 5" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 star and a half out of 5" class="four-star-half">4.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

While i'm trying this:

```
echo"<ul class='star-rating' id='star-rating-'". $star['id'].">
 <li class='current-rating' id='current-rating-".  $star['id']." style='width:". getRating($star['id'])."'%></li>";
 echo'<span class="ratelinks" id="'. $star['id'].'">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star out of 5" class="one-star">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star and a half out of 5" class="one-star-half">1.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 stars out of 5" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 star and a half out of 5" class="two-star-half">2.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 stars out of 5" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 star and a half out of 5" class="three-star-half">3.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 stars out of 5" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 star and a half out of 5" class="four-star-half">4.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
  </span>
</ul>';
```

Comment: _"the result doesn't go the right way"_ - then turn it around. Or explain the real problem. I guess you have to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space between echo and the string. You also have some errors in the string.

```
echo "<ul class='star-rating' id='star-rating-". $star['id']."'>
 <li class='current-rating' id='current-rating-".  $star['id']."' style='width:". getRating($star['id'])."%'></li>";
echo '<span class="ratelinks" id="'. $star['id'].'">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star out of 5" class="one-star">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star and a half out of 5" class="one-star-half">1.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 stars out of 5" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 star and a half out of 5" class="two-star-half">2.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 stars out of 5" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 star and a half out of 5" class="three-star-half">3.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 stars out of 5" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 star and a half out of 5" class="four-star-half">4.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
  </span>
</ul>';
```

I must say that I would love to know the reason of why you would want to make this change?
I would recommend enclosing your string with single-quotes `'`. This way you can still add HTML attributes with the intended double-quotes `"` without having to escape them.

Example:

```
echo '<ul class="star-rating" id="star-rating=' . $star['id'] . '">
  <li class="current-rating" id="current-rating-' . $star['id'] . '" style="width:' . getRating($star['id']) . '%"></li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with large pieces of HTML I'd always suggest using [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and using `{}` to substitue in variables, i.e. `{$star['id']}`.

You'd need to calculate your star rating prior to this heredoc.

```
echo <<<"EOD"
<ul class='star-rating' id="star-rating-{$star['id']}">
<?php /* getRating($id) is to generate current rating */?>
  <li class="current-rating" id="current-rating-{$star['id']}" style="width:{$star_rating['id']}%"><!-- will show current rating --></li>
  <span class="ratelinks" id="<?php echo $star['id'];?>">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star out of 5" class="one-star">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star and a half out of 5" class="one-star-half">1.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 stars out of 5" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 star and a half out of 5" class="two-star-half">2.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 stars out of 5" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 star and a half out of 5" class="three-star-half">3.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 stars out of 5" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 star and a half out of 5" class="four-star-half">4.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
  </span>
</ul>
EOD;
```